# MemoryStream not readable when passed as parameter

Tags: c#, memorystream, dotnetzip

Yesterday I had a strange problem: When I wanted to pass a zip file as `byte[]` and read it, i got an `Ionic.Zip.ZipExpception`

> Cannot read that as a ZipFile

```
public string Import(byte[] file)
{
    try
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(file);
        if (ZipFile.IsZipFile(stream))
        {
            ImportArchive(stream);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    ...
}

private void ImportArchive(MemoryStream stream)
{
    var zip = ZipFile.Read(stream); //--> ZipException thrown
    ...
}
```

Now if I pass the `byte[]` as parameter and not the `MemoryStream`, everything works fine:

```
public string Import(byte[] file)
{
    try
    {                
        if (ZipFile.IsZipFile(new MemoryStream(file), true))
        {
            ImportArchive(file);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    ...
}

private void ImportArchive(byte[] file)
{
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(file);
    var zip = ZipFile.Read(fileStream); //--> no exception!
    ...
}
```

Where is the difference between those two versions? Why can't the first Version of the passed `MemoryStream` be read?

Comment: Have you tried setting the memory streams postion to 0, before you call `ImportArchive` ?

Comment: Perhaps `ZipFile.IsZipFile(stream)` is changing the stream position.  Try setting it to 0 in your `ImportArchive(MemoryStream s)` method before reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ZipFile.IsZipFile` changes the stream position - it needs to read more than one byte of data. You need to "rewind" the stream before calling `ImportArchive`:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

This is not something that can be done automatically - when you pass some method a stream, it's usually assumed that you're pointing to the beginning of the relevant data. This allows you to have different data "packets" in one stream, and it means that you can use streams that aren't seekable.